# Add new view (D) on top of views (ABC) without pushing down (ABC) views

Tags: android

Please help, I have vertical LinearLayout in ScollView as the form of ListView.

I've added about 20 view items inside the LinearLayout and automatically scrolled down to the last item using:

`scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);`

Now when the user have to scroll upwards to to see the top views, I will have to add additional 20 items when the user is almost to the end of the top item.

Yes, I can add item on top using:

`layoutList.addView(itemView, 0):`

but the problem is, the new on top view items will PUSH DOWN the old ones.

I need the new items I added on top should create another space on top to fit in them selves and the old ones should remain in same position when or not scrolling.

For example: When scrolling upwards chat conversations on WhatsApp, some list of previous messages will be added on top and created additional space for themselves to fit-in on top, so the user can as well keep on scrolling upwards

Answer (score 0):

You should use a RecyclerView for this. It will be significantly more efficient and handle the scroll issues you're seeing.

Some example code to do this (many descriptions of `RecyclerView` are available online). This example allows you to add at top or bottom. It'll push down when adding at the top until the screen is full. Then adds on either end happen without scrolling.

```kotlin
// Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val recycler = binding.recycler
        val adapter = MyAdapter()
        recycler.adapter = adapter

        binding.addTop.setOnClickListener {
            adapter.addAtTop()
        }
        binding.addBottom.setOnClickListener {
            adapter.addAtBottom()
        }
    }
}

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(value: String) {
        (itemView as TextView).text = value
    }
}

class MyAdapter: Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {
    private var n = 1
    fun addAtTop() {
        items.add(0, "Item $n")
        n++
        notifyItemInserted(0)
    }
    fun addAtBottom() {
        items.add("Item $n")
        n++
        notifyItemInserted(items.size-1)
    }

    private val items = mutableListOf<String>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val row = RowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(row.root)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<!-- Copyright 2023 Google LLC.          -->
<!-- SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 -->

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_item_at_top"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_item_at_bottom"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright 2023 Google LLC.          -->
<!-- SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 -->

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="48sp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

Be sure to call `notifyItemInserted(0)` when adding at the top instead of `notifyDataSetChanged` when updating the adapter. This gives more detailed hints to the RecyclerView so it will know if the displayed items need to be updated. (You can also `DiffUtil` to compute the changes).

Note that this example uses view binding, so you'll need

In app/build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
// Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. But I've alot of problems using any view the has to do with recycling including ListView due to animation and other stuff. I have no choice but to use LinearLayout in ScollView. I've to optimize the items myself. Thanks

Comment: @Peter What types of problems? You can disable animation if needed. Adding items to a LinearLayout doesn't scale.